# Remover commits de um repositório

Tags: git, request, commit

Eu precisava de alguma forma de remover commits de um fork meu de um repositório e deixar apenas os selecionados. Já tentei usar o git rebase, como sugerido em vários tópicos, mas sem sucesso, as alterações não aplicaram no repositório, além de vários conflitos, exemplo:

```css
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in docs/translations/pt/scripting/functions/SetPlayerFacingAngle.md
```

Os argumentos que usei no git rebase foram: git rebase -i HEAD~5.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que sei, Jhon, git não permite remoção de commits do seu histórico. O máximo que tu podes fazer é um `squash`, como descrito [nesse tutorial](https://medium.com/cwi-software/utilizando-rebase-e-squash-para-melhorar-o-hist%C3%B3rico-do-git-fdb2d952c09c).

Caso tenhas inserido uma alteração indesejada, é um `git reset` (provavelmente algo como `git reset --hard HEAD~1` para votar 1 commit, ou `git reset --hard <commit_id>` para voltar a um commit específico). Mas isso não tira o commit do histórico.

Outra coisa é na configurações nos teus pull requests - em vez de dar apenas merge, tu podes fazer um `squash merge`, para agrupar os commits, transformando os commits do PR em apenas 1.